# Update results (clear last result) if drop down list updates

Tags: excel, vba

I have different names (account managers) in the drop down list and each account manager has 1 or more than 1 'SID' (6 digits number). If i select 'A'(Account manager) who has 3 SIDs, and if but i am want to see 'B' account manager's SID who has only 1 SID, so i want to clear the last result and show only for B account manager, But in my code the last result still there, the code updates the First SID of 'B' and keep other two SIDs of 'A".

I don't require "A" SIDs if i am selecting 'B' (it should only show one and clear rest cells

This is my code:

```
Sub Discrepancies_by_Acc_Mgr()

''SIDs are in column 'D' in my Data,
''Account manager names are in Column 'W',
'' Column 'Z3' where i have my drop down list,
'' From Column 'Z6' where i want to start print the SIDs if find in the data

    s = 6
    For i = 2 To 25000
        If (Worksheets("Data").Range("W" & i)) =(Worksheets("Data").Range("Z3"))  Then
            Worksheets("Data").Range("Z" & s) = Worksheets("Data").Range("D" & i) 
            s = s + 1
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clear the contents of the cells before writing the results:

```
Sub Discrepancies_by_Acc_Mgr()
    Dim s As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Data")  
        'Clear existing contents if they exist
        If Not IsEmpty(.Range("Z6")) Then  
            .Range("Z6:Z" & .Range("Z" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
        End If

        s = 6
        For i = 2 To 25000
            If .Range("W" & i).Value = .Range("Z3").Value  Then
                .Range("Z" & s).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value
                s = s + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```